# Using F-Spot, how can I find the file location for a specific photo?

Tags: f-spot

Several of my parents' photos in F-Spot have gone missing.  I can't seem to figure out the location of the photo file that F-Spot expects to find. I've been looking around for something like "Photo Properties" but so far I haven't seen it.

This is sounding confusing, so hopefully a screenshot will help clear things up:

[image]

- In this photo, F-Spot is missing a picture.
- We can see that the filename is img_0445.jpg.
- I've found the actual photo in my backups.
- I'm having a hard time replacing the missing photo, because I can't figure out in which directory F-Spot is expecting to find the photo.

Is there any way, using F-Spot to find the File Location of a photo?  Something like Banshee's "Open Containing Folder"? I thought previously you could right-click a photo and choose "Copy File Location", but I'm not seeing that option in F-Spot 0.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could interrogate the f-spot database itself to search for the filename in question.  Once found, the file-location that f-spot was expecting will be available.  This method would be particularly useful if you've got lots of pictures to search for.

Install sqlite3:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Now dump the f-spot database:

```
sqlite3 ~/.config/f-spot/photos.db .dump > ~/filelocations.csv
```

Using LibreOffice Calc - open the file `filelocations.csv` and search using the filename with the missing picture.  The filename should exist in two rows - one or both of which should display your missing file location.

for example

[image]

Comment: Good call! I was going to suggest search the database :)

Comment: Good call indeed!  Even better, using the Sqlite Database Browser, I can view the database directly and make updates to the incorrect locations. After making a backup copy, of course. ;)

Answer (score 0):

All the photos are stored in **Photos** folder in **Pictures** folder in your home. And each photo is stored according to the date the photo is taken like this "Pictures/Photos/Year/Month/date".

For example if your photo is taken on 2011-10-20. It is stored in 
**Pictures/Photos/2011/10/20** path.

Comment: Over the years, F-Spot's default location has changed from ~/Photos to ~/Pictures/Photos.  This has left a lot of clutter in various places in the home folder, and I think it's what led to the missing files in the first place.  I need to know -- on a picture-by-picture basis -- where F-Spot is looking for each photo.

Comment: F-spot stores pictures according to the **Date the picture has been taken**. For instance if you have 2 photos taken on 2011-10-20 and 2011-10-21 they will be stored on ~/Pictures/Photos/2011/10/20 and ~/Pictures/Photos/2011/10/21. So what you have to do is check the date the photo has taken (you can do it by right clicking the picture and go to the image tab -- nautilus) and put it in to the specific folder as I have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the date isn't the part of the file location that I'm worried about -- it's the first part.  Some pictures are stored in `~/Pictures/Photos`, some in `~/Pictures` and some in `~/Photos` (and some in various other locations).  *I* can find the photos, but F-Spot can't, and I'd like to know where it's looking for each individual picture (which varies wildly from one photo to another).

Answer (score 0):

I found a (slightly complicated) solution. Right click the photo from the standard view (the one you get when you first Open F-Spot), and choose open with>Image Viewer.

In Image Viewer (in this case EOG), right click the picture and choose properties. It will show you where you photo is.

[image]

Comment: While this works well for regular pictures, I'm fairly sure F-Spot doesn't let you attempt to open missing pictures with external applications.

Comment: @MichaelMS have you tried? If you have, then the only other option will probably be to open the database manually...

Comment: I had tried it a couple days ago, and I just double-checked.  "No Applications Available" for "Open With..." on missing photos. Database it is, then. :)